# What require for JS script ? (exit from android app)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, exit

**What require for exit from android app via JS ?**

I am new user Cordova, Phonegap.

I have cordova (CLI) 5.4.1. , Installed platform android 4.1.1.

I tried use (include to index.html) cordova-1.5.0.js, cordova.js, phonegap-1.4.1.js and I tried many solutions and functions:

1. navigator.app.exitApp()
2. app.exitApp()
3. Device.exitApp()

however, Unfortunately, nothing doesn't work.

**Tell me please: Which namely JS method (function) should I use and corresponding JS file(s) (or JS library) ?**

Thank you in advance!

P.S. I everytime compile, install apk, test on my phone (android 4.1.2)

Comment: Where is the your `CSP` meta element from your index.html?

Comment: What is CSP meta element ? I haven't CSP meta element. I include JS following way: <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script>

Comment: Okay you have a fairly serious problem. I recommend - close this post, or delete it. I've look at your code. You have element of *Cordova CLI*, *Phonegap CLI*, and *Phonegap Build*. You have stumbled into [#1](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) of [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md). The code would never work. I would recommend we go to [Google Group of Cordova/Phonegap](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap)

Comment: Ok, thank you.
I will read it.